# Comparing input to character not working in x86_64 Mac assembly nasm

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm

In nasm assembly on mac with the processor architecture x86_64, I am struggling to compare input to a string or character. When comparing input (stdin) to a character, it's not being true when it should be. I am new to assembly.

Here is my code.

```
global start

section .bss
    input resb 10

section .text
    start:
        ;getting the input
        mov rax, 0x2000003      ;meaning read
        mov rdi, 0
        mov rsi, input
        mov rdx, 10
        syscall ;special

        ;here is where I do the comparing
        mov rax, r
        mov rbx, input
        cmp rax, rbx
        je right        
        
        ;jumping to the return function
        jmp ret

    right:
        mov rax, 0x2000004       ;meaning write
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, right_way
        mov rdx, right_len
        syscall ;special

    ret:
        mov rax, 0x2000001       ;return 0
        xor rdi, rdi         ;which means to make rdi = 0 could be replaced with mov rdi, 0 but xor is faster
        syscall

section .data

    right_way: db "You are correct!", 10, 0
    right_len: equ $-right_way

    r: db "r", 10
```

At the "je right" line, it should jump to the right function but it does not. Do I need to convert the input to something else?
Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're comparing the addresses, not the data there.

Comment: Also you don't need to go through a register at all, you can just do `cmp byte [input], "r"`.

Comment: How do I compare the data rather than the addresses?

Comment: ```cmp byte [input], "r"``` did not work. Error= nasm -f macho64 compare.asmcompare.asm:18: error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses

Comment: `cmp byte [rel input], "r"` or stick `default rel` at the top.

Comment: Thanks! When I included both of them in the code, it worked.

Comment: Another question. Could you tell me how to make assembly compare the input to a string instead of one character?

Comment: Write a loop.  Arbitrary length strings aren't something a CPU can do in a single instruction.  (You can do a fixed compare of 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, or 16 with SSE2).  Think about how you'd do it in C.  If that involves calling a function like `strcmp`, you'd have to implement strcmp logic.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.